# yii2 verbfilter post logout

Tags: php, yii2

I can't imagine what is wrong but now logout not working.
In controller behaviours:

```
'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
```

same as yii2 advanced template. layout (default) has Html::csrfMetaTags(). csrf var sended via post when I click the link 'Logout'. data-method=post is set up. I try to compare http queries with my working another website. it looks like similar. I never get in actionLogut().
What is possible wrong?

Comment: maybe you did not set *access rules* for your logout action ?

Comment: set (default template): access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong. I dnt know exactly. I found that problem with custom UrlManager  from codemix. I logging some vars and found that logout url is /account/logout and urlmanager redirect me to /en/account/logout. I dnt know why UrlManager create logout url without /en/. I played with 'enableDefaultLanguageUrlCode' param and... url become generating rightly! and logout is working